# How to merge two XML files with different child elements into single XML file

Tags: python, django, xml

The below given are my sample xml files.

(XML 1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objects>
   <object>
      <record>
         <organization>1010</organization>
         <code>000010001</code>
         <name>A &amp; SOLICITORS</name>
         <address_1>NORTH</address_1>
         <address_2/>
         <city/>
         <postcode>NUHMAN 1</postcode>
         <state/>
         <country>IE</country>
         <vat_number/>
         <telephone_number>054456849</telephone_number>
         <fax_number>01 64964659</fax_number>
         <currency>USD</currency>
         <start_date>1990-01-01</start_date>
         <end_date>2999-12-31</end_date>
         <status>ACTIVE</status>
      </record>
      <record>
         <organization>1010</organization>
         <code>0000100004</code>
         <name>ACCUTRON LTD.</name>
         <address_1>RAZIK PARK</address_1>
         <address_2/>
         <city>LIME</city>
         <postcode>V94654X7</postcode>
         <state/>
         <country>IE</country>
         <vat_number>IE6566750H</vat_number>
         <telephone_number>353 -61 - 54614</telephone_number>
         <fax_number/>
         <currency>USD</currency>
         <start_date>1990-01-01</start_date>
         <end_date>2999-12-31</end_date>
         <status>ACTIVE</status>
      </record>
```

(XML 2)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objects>
   
      <record>
         <po_number>45670369</po_number>
         <po_currency>USD</po_currency>
         <po_organization>1010</po_organization>
         <code>0000156001</code>
         <name>SOFTWAREONE INC</name>
         <capture_row_type>NONE</capture_row_type>
         <source_system>SAP</source_system>
      </record>
      <record>
         <po_number>45670372</po_number>
         <po_currency>USD</po_currency>
         <po_organization>1010</po_organization>
         <code>0000156001</code>
         <name>SOFTWAREONE INC</name>
         <capture_row_type>NONE</capture_row_type>
         <source_system>SAP</source_system>
      </record>
```

As we can see some of the fields are similar here.

I'm trying to merge these two into one xml in a way that inside the record element each of the data in the two xml's must be there. Both data in the two files are not in order. I want the data with the matching 'code' to be grouped together in the new XML file. Both files have different number of fields and code is on of the common field and I want it to be the common factor for which the data to be grouped together.

How the XML should look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objects>
   <object>
      <record>
         <organization>1010</organization>
         <code>000010001</code>
         <name>A &amp; SOLICITORS</name>
         <address_1>NORTH</address_1>
         <address_2/>
         <city/>
         <postcode>NUHMAN 1</postcode>
         <state/>
         <country>IE</country>
         <vat_number/>
         <telephone_number>054456849</telephone_number>
         <fax_number>01 64964659</fax_number>
         <currency>USD</currency>
         <start_date>1990-01-01</start_date>
         <end_date>2999-12-31</end_date>
         <status>ACTIVE</status>
         <po_number>45670369</po_number>
         <po_currency>USD</po_currency>
         <po_organization>1010</po_organization>
         <name>SOFTWAREONE INC</name>
         <capture_row_type>NONE</capture_row_type>
         <source_system>SAP</source_system>
      </record>
```

Comment: How would the grouped/merged result look like for the two samples?

Comment: I have posted how my result should look like

Comment: Please ensure that the XML samples are well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas:

`S1.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objects>
   <object>
      <record>
         <organization>1010</organization>
         <code>000010001</code>
         <name>A &amp; SOLICITORS</name>
         <address_1>NORTH</address_1>
         <address_2/>
         <city/>
         <postcode>NUHMAN 1</postcode>
         <state/>
         <country>IE</country>
         <vat_number/>
         <telephone_number>054456849</telephone_number>
         <fax_number>01 64964659</fax_number>
         <currency>USD</currency>
         <start_date>1990-01-01</start_date>
         <end_date>2999-12-31</end_date>
         <status>ACTIVE</status>
      </record>
      <record>
         <organization>1010</organization>
         <code>0000100004</code>
         <name>ACCUTRON LTD.</name>
         <address_1>RAZIK PARK</address_1>
         <address_2/>
         <city>LIME</city>
         <postcode>V94654X7</postcode>
         <state/>
         <country>IE</country>
         <vat_number>IE6566750H</vat_number>
         <telephone_number>353 -61 - 54614</telephone_number>
         <fax_number/>
         <currency>USD</currency>
         <start_date>1990-01-01</start_date>
         <end_date>2999-12-31</end_date>
         <status>ACTIVE</status>
      </record>
   </object>
</objects>
```

`S2.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objects>
      <record>
         <po_number>45670369</po_number>
         <po_currency>USD</po_currency>
         <po_organization>1010</po_organization>
         <code>0000156001</code>
         <name>SOFTWAREONE INC</name>
         <capture_row_type>NONE</capture_row_type>
         <source_system>SAP</source_system>
      </record>
      <record>
         <po_number>45670372</po_number>
         <po_currency>USD</po_currency>
         <po_organization>1010</po_organization>
         <code>0000156001</code>
         <name>SOFTWAREONE INC</name>
         <capture_row_type>NONE</capture_row_type>
         <source_system>SAP</source_system>
      </record>
</objects>
```

`python code`:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_xml('S1.xml', xpath="//record")
df2 = pd.read_xml('S2.xml', xpath="//record")
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
df3.to_xml('S3.xml', index=False, root_name='object', row_name='record')
```

`S3.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<object>
  <record>
    <organization>1010</organization>
    <code>156001</code>
    <name>SOFTWAREONE INC</name>
    <address_1>NORTH</address_1>
    <address_2/>
    <city/>
    <postcode>NUHMAN 1</postcode>
    <state/>
    <country>IE</country>
    <vat_number/>
    <telephone_number>054456849</telephone_number>
    <fax_number>01 64964659</fax_number>
    <currency>USD</currency>
    <start_date>1990-01-01</start_date>
    <end_date>2999-12-31</end_date>
    <status>ACTIVE</status>
    <po_number>45670369</po_number>
    <po_currency>USD</po_currency>
    <po_organization>1010</po_organization>
    <capture_row_type>NONE</capture_row_type>
    <source_system>SAP</source_system>
  </record>
  <record>
    <organization>1010</organization>
    <code>156001</code>
    <name>SOFTWAREONE INC</name>
    <address_1>RAZIK PARK</address_1>
    <address_2/>
    <city>LIME</city>
    <postcode>V94654X7</postcode>
    <state/>
    <country>IE</country>
    <vat_number>IE6566750H</vat_number>
    <telephone_number>353 -61 - 54614</telephone_number>
    <fax_number/>
    <currency>USD</currency>
    <start_date>1990-01-01</start_date>
    <end_date>2999-12-31</end_date>
    <status>ACTIVE</status>
    <po_number>45670372</po_number>
    <po_currency>USD</po_currency>
    <po_organization>1010</po_organization>
    <capture_row_type>NONE</capture_row_type>
    <source_system>SAP</source_system>
  </record>
</object>
```